# Clarification on TypeScript's noUnusedParameters compiler option

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to determine if this is, in fact, a bug before entering anything on GitHub.

With `noUnusedParameters` enabled, the TypeScript compiler will error on something like:

```
const foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
foo.forEach((item: string, index: number) => {
  // do something just with index, ignoring item
});
```

with `error TS6133: 'item' is declared but never used.` But while it's not specifically used, it is being used in that the second argument to the `forEach` iterator function is the index.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no need to file an issue, as one already exists: [with --noUnusedParameters how can i skip uneeded parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9458).

**tl;dr:**
You can skip this error by prefixing the uninteresting arguments with underscore:

```
const foo = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
foo.forEach((_item: string, index: number) => {
    console.log(index);
});
```

Compiles fine.

Comment: Oh sweet.  I saw this in tslint (https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/1337), but didn't realize it got incorporated into core TypeScript.  Apologies for missing the existing issue.  I thought I did a better job of searching them first.  Thanks.

Comment: Is this in the docs anywhere? Random github threads have a tendency of being outdated as features get deprecated (and sometimes un-deprecated and re-deprecated in this case).

Comment: @tryangul the only thing close to documentation on this (that I know of) is a short explanation and example in the [What's new in TypeScript 2.6](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#write-only-references-now-flagged-as-unused)

Comment: @tryangul Same boat; I'd like to find something "more official" too. Best I've seen is some [old discussion on TSLint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues/3442), and the convention seems to have carried over.