# how can I avoid TS6133 errors when using anonymous methods?

Tags: typescript

We have a TypeScript project that I am trying to clean-up a bit.
I started turning on stricter type-checking. Today, I just enabled `noUnusedParameters` in `tsconfig.json`.

We use `expressJS` and the following code is getting flagged with a `error TS6133: 'req' is declared but never used.`

How can I rewrite this to comply?

```ts
import * as express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Obviously, I have to declare `req` if I want to have `res`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can resolve this error by prefixing or replacing the unused parameters with an underscore. In this case, you could prefix `req` as `_req`:

```
app.get('/', (_req, res) => {
  ...
});
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41685054/clarification-on-typescripts-nounusedparameters-compiler-option) for more details.

Comment: Any pointers for TSLint's `[tslint] variable name must be in lowerCamelCase, PascalCase or UPPER_CASE (variable-name)` ? it seems I can simply name it `__` or add the `disable` rule comments.

Comment: There's a tslint option for `variable-name` to allow leading underscores. https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/variable-name/